# How to debug exception from bootstrap grid.less and ClearScriptV8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, less, v8, bundletransformer

All of a sudden (so it seems) a perfectly working MVC5 with Bootstrap (LESS) solution refuses to run. When I attempt to run, it just gives me blank screen and the site never loads.

When I run in debug mode, after about 90 seconds, it crashes with this exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in ClearScriptV8-32.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

*However the solution will run fine if I remove `/bootstrap/less/grid.less`.*

**Things I've Tried**

I've tried swapping the V8 engine for Msie. This also suggests that `grid.less` is a problem, in particular it points to this line: `.make-grid(sm);`

I tried turning off my AV as I saw that suggested somewhere. It didn't make any difference.

I have googled around it and the only obviously relevant info I found was this link. It suggests turning off pooling, but I'm not sure how to do this - or if it's even relevant to my solution - because I don't have a `ReactConfig.cs` file:

https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/102

I'm a bit out of my depth. Could anybody help or suggest ways for me to research / debug this problem?

Thanks!!

---

**I found the problem. The bootstrap LESS files were being included twice. Answer below.**

---

**Stack Trace Using V8 Engine**

```
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ContextProxyImpl.Execute(String gcDocumentName, String gcCode, Boolean evaluate, Boolean discard)
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<Execute>b__19()
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.ScriptEngine.ScriptInvoke[T](Func`1 func)
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine.BaseScriptInvoke[T](Func`1 func)
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine.<>c__DisplayClass25`1.<ScriptInvoke>b__24()
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.?A0x792c8756.LockCallback(Void* pvArg)
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ContextProxyImpl.InvokeWithLock(Action gcAction)
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine.ScriptInvoke[T](Func`1 func)
  at Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine.Execute(String documentName, String code, Boolean evaluate, Boolean discard)
  at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngine.InnerEvaluate(String expression)
  at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngine.InnerEvaluate[T](String expression)
  at JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineBase.Evaluate[T](String expression)
  at BundleTransformer.Less.Internal.LessCompiler.Compile(String content, String path)
  at BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.InnerTranslate(IAsset asset, LessCompiler lessCompiler, Boolean enableNativeMinification)
  at BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.Translate(IList`1 assets)
  at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Translate(IList`1 assets, Boolean isDebugMode)
  at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Transform(IList`1 assets, BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse, VirtualPathProvider virtualPathProvider, Boolean isDebugMode)
  at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse, Boolean isDebugMode)
  at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse)
  at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles)
  at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
  at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
  at System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath)
  at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets)
  at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
  at System.Web.Optimization.Styles.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
  at System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render(String[] paths)
  at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\MHL\OneDrive - FP\FpAccounting\FpAccounting\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 7
```

**Stack Trace Using Msie Engine**

```
    BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.AssetTranslationException was unhandled by user code
    HResult=-2146233088
    Message=During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file '/Content/Less/config.less', to CSS-code syntax error has occurred. 
  See more details:

  Error type: Syntax
  Message: Out of stack space
  File: /ThirdPartyPlugins/bootstrap/less/grid.less
  Line number: 66
  Column number: 3
  Source error:

  Line 65: @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  Line 66:   .make-grid(sm);
  -----------^
  Line 67: }


    Source=BundleTransformer.Less
    StackTrace:
         at BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.InnerTranslate(IAsset asset, LessCompiler lessCompiler, Boolean enableNativeMinification)
         at BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.Translate(IList`1 assets)
         at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Translate(IList`1 assets, Boolean isDebugMode)
         at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Transform(IList`1 assets, BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse, VirtualPathProvider virtualPathProvider, Boolean isDebugMode)
         at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse, Boolean isDebugMode)
         at BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.TransformerBase.Process(BundleContext bundleContext, BundleResponse bundleResponse)
         at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles)
         at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
         at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context)
         at System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath)
         at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets)
         at System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
         at System.Web.Optimization.Styles.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths)
         at System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render(String[] paths)
         at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\MHL\OneDrive - FP\FpAccounting\FpAccounting\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 7
         at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
         at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
         at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
         at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer)
         at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
         at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
         at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
         at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
         at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
         at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
         at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
         at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
         at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
         at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
         at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
    InnerException:
```

**Bootstrap grid.less**

```
  //
  // Grid system
  // --------------------------------------------------


  // Container widths
  //
  // Set the container width, and override it for fixed navbars in media queries.

  .container {
    .container-fixed();

    @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
      width: @container-sm;
    }
    @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
      width: @container-md;
    }
    @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
      width: @container-lg;
    }
  }


  // Fluid container
  //
  // Utilizes the mixin meant for fixed width containers, but without any defined
  // width for fluid, full width layouts.

  .container-fluid {
    .container-fixed();
  }


  // Row
  //
  // Rows contain and clear the floats of your columns.

  .row {
    .make-row();
  }


  // Columns
  //
  // Common styles for small and large grid columns

  .make-grid-columns();


  // Extra small grid
  //
  // Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for extra small devices like
  // smartphones.

  .make-grid(xs);


  // Small grid
  //
  // Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the small device range, from phones
  // to tablets.

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    .make-grid(sm);
  }


  // Medium grid
  //
  // Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the desktop device range.

  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    .make-grid(md);
  }


  // Large grid
  //
  // Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the large desktop device range.

  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    .make-grid(lg);
  }
```

**JsEngineSwitcherConfig.cs**

```
public class JsEngineSwitcherConfig
{
    public static void Configure(JsEngineSwitcher engineSwitcher)
    {
        engineSwitcher.EngineFactories
            .AddV8();
        engineSwitcher.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
    }
}
```

**... called in Global.asax**

```
JsEngineSwitcherConfig.Configure(JsEngineSwitcher.Instance);
```

**And in Web.config**

```
 <bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
   <less useNativeMinification="false" ieCompat="true" strictMath="false" strictUnits="false" dumpLineNumbers="None">
     <jsEngine name="V8JsEngine" />
   </less>
   <core>
     <css>
       <translators>
         <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />

       <add name="LessTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator, BundleTransformer.Less" /></translators>
       <postProcessors>
         <add name="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor" type="BundleTransformer.Core.PostProcessors.UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor, BundleTransformer.Core" useInDebugMode="false" />
       </postProcessors>
       <minifiers>
         <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
       </minifiers>
       <fileExtensions>
         <add fileExtension=".css" assetTypeCode="Css" />

       <add fileExtension=".less" assetTypeCode="Less" /></fileExtensions>
     </css>
     <js>
       <translators>
         <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
       </translators>
       <minifiers>
         <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
       </minifiers>
       <fileExtensions>
         <add fileExtension=".js" assetTypeCode="JavaScript" />
       </fileExtensions>
     </js>
   </core>
 </bundleTransformer>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with a plugin (https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog).

It had LESS and CSS files.

While the CSS file only contained styles for the plugin itself, the LESS file contained the whole bootstrap LESS in addition to the plugin style!

Thus the variables and mixins were being included a second time.